# Não consigo criar um Schema no mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Olá!

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o mongoose. Estou tentando criar um model, mas o terminal está retornando o seguinte erro: 
"Cannot read property 'Schema' of undefined"

Onde eu estou errando?

Seguem os códigos:

User.ts

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const  UserSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
register: {
    type: Date
}
});

export const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

index.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { connect } from './app/database/db';
import { User }  from './app/models/User';

const server = express();

if (connect) {
console.log('Conentado à base de dados com suceso.');

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor rodando em http://localhost:3000');
    } 
);
} else {
    console.log('Erro ao tentar conectar à base de dados.');
}

server.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    User.find()
.then((users) => {
    res.json({
        confirmation: "Success!",
        data: users
    })
})
.catch((err) => {
    res.json({
        confirmation: "Fail.",
        message: err.message
    })
})
})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mongoose pode não ter a declaração `export default`, então tente importa-lo com `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'`.

Answer (score 0):

Assim deve solucionar seu problema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    register: {
        type: Date
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique a primeira e ultima linha do seu script:
Na primeira linha: `import mongoose from 'mongoose';`
Alterar para :`const mongoose - require('mongoose')`

Na ultima linha: `export const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);`
Alterar para: `module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)`

Com essas alterações já consegue avançar com o mongoose.